Error when converting forecast_it to list in GluonTS Transformer Predictor: "Setting an array element with a sequence"
I'm using GluonTS to make time series predictions with the TransformerPredictor. However, when I try to convert the forecast_it iterator to a list, I encounter the following error:
Setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (15, 11) + inhomogeneous part. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: source array must be array like object
train_data = ListDataset(
    [{
        'start': df.index[0],
        'target': df['target'].values,
        'feat_dynamic_real': df['feat_dynamic_real'].values.T,
        'feat_static_cat': df['feat_static_cat'].values if 'feat_static_cat' in df.columns else None
    }],
    freq='D'
)

predictor = TransformerPredictor(
    input_size=1,
    prediction_length=30,
    freq='D',
    context_length=30,
    trainer=Trainer(epochs=10)
)

predictor.train(train_data)

forecast_it, ts_it = make_evaluation_predictions(dataset=train_data, predictor=predictor)

forecasts = list(forecast_it)  # This line raises the error

Tried ensuring all the time series are of equal lengths. Did not resolve the issue.
Let me know if you need any additional information—this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow

Running into this same issue. Did you ever figure out what was happening?
